# AWS Elastic Beanstalk ERROR: InvalidParameterValueError

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-elb

While using command - eb deploy

I am getting below error. YAML is fine syntax wise

ERROR: InvalidParameterValueError - Each option setting in configuration file .ebextensions/environ-
v1.config in application version app-4c59-191023_045651 must be a map. Update each option setting in the configuration file.

[image]

.config file in .ebextensions folder which is in root of project

`option_settings:
   aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
     PORT:8081
     NODE_ENV:development
   aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:
     SecurityGroups:launch-123`

Comment: please share your yaml relevant portions

Comment: @JunedAhsan added yaml relevent portion

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue running the AWS Deploy a Django App to Elastic Beanstalk (the tutorial does not seem to be up to date).

[This AWS page has some info on the latest option setting formatting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions-optionsettings.html)

It helped me resolve my issue which I think in your case would be including spaces after "PORT: ", "NODE_ENV: ", etc.

Also using an IDE that will highlight different words/parts of the file helped me understand how things were getting recognized.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried double quotes in .config file like

```
"aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
```

instead of

```
aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
```

and, respectively,

```
"aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration":
```

instead of

```
aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:
```